# How to cluster sentences based on same word?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, cluster-analysis

Here is my sample data :

```
maybe add a higher-level description
min of spare daemons
data in the appropriate order
the compiled max daemons
an iovec to store the trailer sent after the ﬁle
data in the wrong order
an iovec to store the headers sent before the ﬁle
return err maybe add a higher-level desc
if a user manually creates a data ﬁle
```

I want to conduct a cluster approach and automatically put these data into categories based 
on same word appear in the sentence, so what I am trying to achieve is like this:

1. add

   maybe add a higher-level description

   return err maybe add a higher-level desc
2. damons

   min of spare daemons

   the compiled max daemons
3. iovec

   an iovec to store the headers sent before the ﬁle

   an iovec to store the trailer sent after the ﬁle
4. data

   data in the wrong order

   data in the appropriate order

   if a user manually creates a data ﬁle

Could anyone give me some help? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds as if you want to find the **most frequent words**?

Not really hard to do (and not "clustering", just counting and grouping by the frequent word), what have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: Thank you a lot Anony, I think our answer is what I am looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you're specifically looking for is a **minimal covering**. Each sentence could be "covered" by any of the words in it, and you want a set of words that will cover each sentence at least once, correct?

You can read specifically about this kind of problem at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem -- and in fact, to do so perfectly in NP Complete.

One way would be a simple greedy algorithm, looking for a word that covers the most sentences (most frequent word in the set, no double-counting sentences), then taking that group and moving on to whatever's left.

There are plenty of cases where this is far from optimal, especially if you want the group to be of similar size. You might actually want to throw out words that cover too many -- depending on the set, for instance, "program" could appear in many items without being particularly relevant to most of them.

In this case, it becomes a problem of finding what's *relevant*. Maybe it would make sense to have some sort of parameter, A, for the number of groups, and then you program can aim for words that each give roughly N/A sentences? Count word frequencies, look for that point (a frequency of N/A), and then slowly add words until everything is covered. And then at the end a post-phase in order to try to combine subsets of a common set in order to make it overall cleaner.

Comment: Hi, Alex, thank you a lot for your kind reply, I leant a lot from it, hope you all the best!